# Data Encryption Standard(DES) zipped is bigger?

Tags: encryption

I kind of know why its bigger when DES files are zipped are bigger but can anyone give me proper reason why or link i cant seem to find anything why ?

Thanks :)

Comment: You may want to search for more generic terms next time, e.g. compress then encrypt results in this Q/A:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13181309/compression-and-encryption (I won't mark it as dupe as searches may lead to the correct answer of cHao...)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A decently encrypted ciphertext looks very much like a sequence of random numbers to the compression program.  Without the patterns that'd be present in cleartext, the compressor can't find much redundancy to remove, and thus can't compress very well at all.  Add in the data the compressor needs in order to be able to decode, and it's entirely possible that the "compressed" file will be bigger than the original.

If you want to compress, you might consider doing so before you encrypt.

Comment: In fact, one of the simplest ways to detect encrypted data is to compress it. If it gets smaller, it's probably not encrypted.

Comment: @EricLaw: That is a good test but not foolproof. For example, a block cipher used in ECB mode will often yield very compressible output. There is a famous example of the image of the linux penguin encrypted with a block cipher in ECB mode. That cipher file would probably compress very well.